Count if name matches and outcome is complete
I have a list of names on one sheet. If it's required we need to assit a certain person more, we add the same name to another sheet. I need to count how many times the name is on both sheets and  has an outcome of completed. Here is a basica examlple
Sheet1



Names
Extra Help?
Complete?




Jarrod
No
Yes


Trevor
Yes
Yes



Sheet2



Names




Trevor



So the result should be 1. Trevor is on both sheets and has an outcome of completed.
I have tried comparing the strigns multiple different ways and got no resutls

I have added few more data as example. Suppose sheet1 data-

And sheet2 data. Then use-
=SUM(INDEX(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2:A4,Sheet1!C:C,"Yes")))



Works perfect! Thanks so much!

Another alternative using QUERY function;
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:C,"Select Count(A) Where A Matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, Sheet2!A2:A) & "' And C= 'Yes' Label Count(A) ''")

